# How to hide n numbers of TD in each TR

Tags: jquery

Present i am trying to show the 4 data rows default in each TR even it's less then four rows in TR. And the second thing want to hide rest of rows in each TR.
Finally when i clicked on show button all rows needs to be appear.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Code ref: http://jsfiddle.net/4PCJw/1

Comment: That is wrong.You kept tr in tr

Comment: actually in java used tr:iterator so any other way to get solution.

Comment: you have to fix your html. you cannot have <tr> inside <tr>. http://jsfiddle.net/4PCJw/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created `tr` in `tr` which is `wrong`
Your code should be like:

**HTML:**

```
<table id="effect">
    <tr id="complete">
        <td>0000000</td>
        <td>1111111</td>
        <td>2222222</td>
        <td>0000000</td>
        <td>1111111</td>
        <td>2222222</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="reject">
        <td>aaaaaaa</td>
        <td>bbbbbbb</td>
        <td>ccccccc</td>
    </tr>

</table>

<button id="button">show</button>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
$(function(){

    $(" #complete td").each(function(index){
        if(index>3)
            $(this).hide();
    });
    $(" #reject td").each(function(index){
        if(index>3)
            $(this).hide();
    });

    $( "#button" ).click(function() {
        if($(this).text()=='show more') // whatever your initial value  
             $(this).text('show less');
        else
             $(this).val('show more');
        $(" #complete td").each(function(index){
            if(index>3)
                $(this).toggle();
        });
        $(" #reject td").each(function(index){
            if(index>3)
                $(this).toggle();
        });
    });  
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4PCJw/3/)

Comment: can we have a chance to Show title when need to see more rows. and the same button want to be place like Hide.

Answer (score 2):

Shorter version of Rohan Kumar's code:

http://jsfiddle.net/4PCJw/5/

```
var $keepComplete = $("#complete td").slice(4).hide(),
    $keepReject = $("#reject td").slice(4).hide();

$("#button").click(function () {
    $keepComplete.toggle();
    $keepReject.toggle();
});
```